# jQuery $.post not passing all data

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I've got a jQuery $.post script which isn't passing all of the data to the php script it's calling.  It worked fine when I only passed two parameters into the data field, but now that I've got more than just two, it's not working any more.  The console is showing the values of the fields, but the data isn't being inserted into the database for some reason.

**HTML Form**

```
<fieldset for="center">
    <label>Center:</label>
    <div class="select" name="center" id="center">
        <div class="arrow"></div>
        <div class="option-menu">
            <?php
                $query = "SELECT * FROM $centers";
                $result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);
                $center_name;
                while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
                    $center_name = "{$row['center']}";
                    echo "<div class='option'>" .$center_name ."</div>";
                }
            ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</fieldset>
<fieldset for="initials">
    <label>Initials:</label>
    <input type="text" name="initials" id="initials" />
</fieldset>
<fieldset for="recurrent">
    <label>Type:</label>
    <div class="select" name="recurrent" id="recurrent">
        <div class="arrow"></div>
        <div class="option-menu">
            <?php
                $query = "SELECT * FROM $recurrent";
                $result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);
                while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
                    $type = "{$row['type']}";
                    echo "<div class='option'>" .$type ."</div>";
                }
            ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</fieldset>
```

**PHP Script**

```
ob_start();
require("../includes/header.php");
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){
    $center = $_POST["center"];
    $recurrent = $_POST["recurrent"];
    $initials = $_POST["initials"];
    $query = "INSERT INTO `$scenarios`(`initials`, `center`, `recurrent`) VALUES('" .$initials ."', " .$center ."', '" .$recurrent ."')";

    mysqli_query($connect, $query);
}

    ob_clean();
    echo json_encode(array("success" => 1));
```

**jQuery Script**

```
$("input[id='save']").on("click", function(){
    var initials = $("#initials").val();
    var center = $("#center_menu").val();
    var recurrent = $("#recurrent_menu").val();
    console.log(initials);
    console.log(center);
    console.log(recurrent);
    $.post("../php/processing.php", {initials: initials, center: center, recurrent: recurrent}, function(response){
        if(response.success == "1"){
        }
    }, "json");
})
```

Comment: Do you get an SQL or PHP error message of any kind?  My guess is that the SQL is invalid because you are not escaping the input values before adding them to the SQL.

Comment: You don't need to escape the input values when they're passed via variables.

Comment: Sure you do.  Say that `$_POST["initials"]` contained a string which had a single quote in it like `'A`.  That would make your SQL something like `INSERT INTO $scenarios(initials, center, recurrent) VALUES(''A', '...`, which is not valid.

Comment: You're not talking about SQL escaping, you're talking about form validation and SQL injection.

Comment: Is this a typo or you are missing a quote near "$center" in your query ---     $query = "INSERT INTO `$scenarios`(`initials`, `center`, `recurrent`) VALUES('" .$initials ."', (SINGLE QUOTE MISSING HERE)" .$center ."', '" .$recurrent ."')";

Comment: @RobbyT15 Right, sorry if I wasn't clear.  Anyway, you seem to have figured it out on your own, so my guess was not correct anyway.

Comment: @Dinesh I actually just caught that right before you posted it.

Comment: @Austin, yeah, it was a stupid missing quote.  Ah programming

Answer (score 0):

In your php script, the single quotes are the wrong type of single quotes.

**Change:**

```
$query = "INSERT INTO `$scenarios`(`initials`, `center`, `recurrent`) VALUES('" .$initials ."', " .$center ."', '" .$recurrent ."')";
```

**To:**

```
$query = "INSERT INTO '$scenarios'('initials', 'center`, 'recurrent') VALUES('" .$initials ."', " .$center ."', '" .$recurrent ."')";
```

Comment: Actually, when you're referencing the tables and fields, you use ``, not single quotes.

Answer (score 0):

First, confirm that you aren't getting the proper values back by writing out the values of the three post variables. Be sure that its a problem with the jquery post.

If it is a jquery problem, which parameter isn't getting passed back?

Comment: As I said, the console logs are showing that the values are there.  However, the initials value is the one that has 'broken' the script.  If I were to change everything and just do center and recurrent, the database fields would be populated.

Comment: But the console only shows what jquery is seeing. Add some outputs on the php side to see what is getting rec'd back.

Comment: Ah, yes, I see a single-quote missing before the " .$center ."'

Comment: Yep, that's what was causing the issue.